# How do I use GDI to draw text around a circular path?

Tags: winapi, gdi

I need to draw text onto a window HDC along a circular path using C/C++, and I'm getting google-eyed from searching for several hours. Can someone point me to a good reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Text on Path](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Text_on_Path_with_VBNET.aspx) (Code Project) it uses GDI+ instead of GDI, but I'm sure you will manged.

Comment: GDI is not very nice for doing something like this. I second the GDI+ route.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you see this API descriptions in Windows SDK:
CreateFont, DrawTextEx, ExtTextOut, PolyTextOut.